# I want to store all values from all input fields in an array using $_POST. if I echo $info[0] I get an error o is an undefined offset

Tags: php, html

I want to store all values from all input fields in an array using `$_POST`. here is my code. if I `echo $info[0]` I get an error o is an undefined offset

```
<html>
   <head><time>My Practice</time></head>
   <body>
      <form method="POST" action="">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>First Name</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="fname"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Last Name</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="lname"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Email</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="email"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Password</td>
               <td><input type="text" name="pass"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td> <input type="submit" name="sub" /></td>
            </tr>
            </tr> 
         </table>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
<?php if(isset($_POST['sub'])){ $info = array('var1' => $_POST['fname'], 'var2' => $_POST['lname'] ,'var3' => $_POST['email'] , 'var4' => $_POST['pass']); echo $info[1]; } ?>
```

Comment: Put little bit of effort and **properly format** your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$info = array($_POST['fname'],$_POST['lname'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['pass']);
echo $info[1];//will display lastname
```

Comment: ohky thank you ..it helps me